# New PHP file is not reading the new sass file

Tags: wordpress, sass

I am jumping into an existing Wordpress website and adding new pages and scss files. I was able to get the new php page and scss file up into Wordpress via FileZilla. I created a new scss file with the underscore in front and added the @import in the app.scss file. (I even tried the @use) The content is displaying on the webpage, but it is not reading any of the css that was specifically written for it, not even putting it into the app.scss file.

```
<div class="preloader"></div>

<div class="App">
      <div class="loop_container">
        <div class="text-container">
          <div class="product-info">
            <div class="top-info">
              <div class="product-title">
                <div class="title"><?php the_field('ev_charger_headline');?></div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-header">
                <?php the_field('ev_charger_sub_headline');?>
              </div>
              <div class="product-description">
                <?php the_field('ev_charger_content');?>
              </div>
              <div style="display: flex;" >
                <div class="product-button">Spec Sheet</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-info">
              <?php the_field('ev_charger_more_content'); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product-image">
            <?php 
                $image = get_field('ev_charger_image');
                if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is some of the css:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif !important;
}

.App {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.product-info-options {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #8894a8;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.product-info {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container {
  background: linear-gradient(#22d6c7 50%, white 50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I've tried putting the simple css in the app.scss file to test it, .loop_container{background: blue;} it did not work
I'm not sure what I'm missing or what step I overlooked.

Comment: SASS or SCSS needs to be complied into CSS.

Comment: "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "dist": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --mode development"
  },
this is in the package.json file. how do I run this command?

Comment: Generally, you cannot run them on the server as its made for dev/local. You most likely need to pull down the whole site and setup/install.